# Flot (flot.js) only populated entries in legend

Tags: javascript, flot

*First, I want to apologise for any mistakes in asking the question properly according to the site rules, it's my first time doing it and I tried my best.*

So I have the following issue:

Let's say I have that data (consider it - date / value):

[image]

I then init a chart with it, the only relevant option to that moment is:

```
 xaxis: { mode: "time" }
```

and I get the following result:

[image]

*("Дек" == December)*

Now my problem is that there are mid-day hours in the legend which I don't want. I want only days in it. I tried adding this to the xasis:

```
 tickSize: [1, "day"]
```

but it creates a legend entry for each day of the whole timespan (*01.12, 02.12, 03.12 and so on to 06.12*) and I want only the days for which I have some data present.

Comment: I'm not familiar with flot, but a google search led me to believing you need to set your xaxis mode to `null` instead of `time`. You can now adjust your x axis as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while spent in searching in documentation and google I found that there is actually another property for this:

```
  minTickSize: [1, "day"]
```

That does the trick.